# Create a setup.exe file without any dependent files

Tags: installshield, setup.exe

I am a first time user of this group and so pardon me for any mistakes and unclear statements.

What I am trying to do is to create single setup.exe (not msi) using installshield. But when I build the project what I get is other files along with the .exe file for e.g. .cab, .hdr, .inx and other such files.
I am using the options under Release -> Release Wizard -> General options-> Checked the "Create a single file executable" & "Compress compiled script" options but still I get the extra files along with the setup.exe file. I want a setup.exe file to be created independent of the other local files.

So could anyone suggest me how to achieve that.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are always created for InstallScript projects. When you build a single file executable, the single file version that packages it all together is available in an adjacent folder.

Comment: Thanks Michael and gilad.. I got the single exe file. That was helpful

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Urman wrote, you will find the one file in adjacent folder.
The folder name is "Package".